# Избежать повторного вызова foreach (ob)

Tags: php, foreach, str-replace

Как можно сократить этот код, использующий функции контроля вывода (ob)? Возможно избежать повторного вызова foreach? [Выполнить код (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0e1ba04da412aef7a7b84fe3176eb2e3e8066f1)

```
ob_start();
echo "#F_NAME#";
echo "#F_PHONE#";
$props = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

foreach ($codes as $code)
{
    switch ($code) 
    {
        case "F_NAME":
            $str = 0;
            break;
        case "F_PHONE":
            $str = 1;
            break;
    }

$props = str_replace(
        '#'.$code.'#',
        $str,
        $props);
}

echo $props."\n";

ob_start();
echo "#F_EMAIL#";
echo "#F_ADDRESS#";
$props = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

foreach ($codes as $code)
{
    switch ($code) 
    {
        case "F_EMAIL":
            $str = 2;
            break;
        case "F_ADDRESS":
            $str = 3;
            break;
    }

$props = str_replace(
        '#'.$code.'#',
        $str,
        $props);
}

echo $props."\n";
```

Comment: Не помешало бы описание, чего вы хотите добиться в результате - замена неких подстрок из буфера? Если да, то тут и вовсе без цикла можно обойтись.

Comment: Дело в том что `echo "#F_NAME#"; echo "#F_PHONE#";` и `echo "#F_EMAIL#"; echo "#F_ADDRESS#";` вызываются в разных функциях.

Comment: Условимся, что в этом примере невозможно изменить положение вызова echo.

Comment: Решил вопрос глобальной переменной.